# How to detect Blink in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, chromium, blink

Is there any way to detect that the user is coming with Blink or Webkit powered Chrome engine? By the way i'm also curious about if i can check somewhere if my browser is with blink or not.

Comment: Where do you want to check this? Javascript or a server side programming language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blink is Chrome 28+.
So if you are already detecting Chrome via its useragent you could just check: `version >= 28` Though not fully reliable if the user agent is spoofed, obviously.

<strike>For an additional more reliable way you can check the [chrome.notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html) API status which became available/stable with Blink/Chrome28+ (on ChromeOS, Windows, and Mac and then Android 4.4)</strike>

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784028/1647538) for ref, and this [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137297) for details.

UPDATE: That previous idea was complicated and unreliable. I removed it.

I ran into a feature that was added with Chrome 28 (namely [CSS.supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS.supports)) which is easier and cleaner:

```
if ((window.chrome || (window.Intl && Intl.v8BreakIterator)) && 'CSS' in window){
//Blink Engine
}
```

UPDATE 2: Added an extra check because some Blink browsers like Opera Mobile or Maxthon lack the `window.chrome` object. A v8 feature check is necessary to cover all current Blink engine browsers as of Dec 2014.

And for completeness since you asked for a server side programming language too:
On the server side or even for JS eventually, just look for `WebKit/537.36`. Only a Blink user agent will have that Webkit version. No official Safari version was released with that build number as far as I can tell. However, watch for the `IEMobile`, `Trident` or `Edge` tokens since [Windows IE now imitate *Android and Blink*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: So, would the '537.36' be a reliable check for Blink, now, for Chromium and Opera as well?

Comment: @ShaharOr If the userAgent is not spoofed, yes. The only potential false positive case you could see from a *legit* user, is if they use Desktop Mode on a Mobile device which might spoof a Blink Agent.

Comment: @ShaharOr FYI, just tested it - testing for `window.CSS` applies to Opera with Blink as well :)

Answer (score 0):

> [...] detect that the user is coming with Blink or Webkit **powered Chrome engine**

In case you'd like to detect a *Chromium* browser regardless of how its layout engine is called ("Webkit", "Blink", "FutureEngine3000") or how the browser shell is commercially named ("Chrome", "Edge", "Brave", ...), try the **[User-Agent Client Hints](https://github.com/WICG/ua-client-hints)** API:

```js
{
  const isChromium = brand => brand.brand === "Chromium";
  console.log(!!globalThis.navigator?.userAgentData?.brands?.some(isChromium));
}
```

For other properties, see https://user-agent-client-hints.glitch.me/javascript.html.